# How to track a user's location and display the path travelled using MapBox iOS sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, dictionary, mapbox

how to display path using RMShape?

I want to do live tracker and drawing travel line.

```
- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(KRRMAnnotation *)annotation
{
    if (annotation.isUserLocationAnnotation)
        return nil;

    KRCalloutView *calloutView = [[[UINib nibWithNibName:@"KRRMCalloutView" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    calloutView.maxTitleLabelWidth = 250.0f;
    [calloutView setTitle:annotation.placeModel.title withAttributes:[KRStyleUtilities mapViewCalloutTextAttributes]];

    KRRMMarker *marker = [[KRRMMarker alloc]initWithUIImage:annotation.placeModel.pinImage andContentView:calloutView inMapView:mapView];
    marker.delegate = self.markerDelegateHandler;
    marker.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    marker.correctCalloutPositionEnabled = YES;
    marker.canShowCallout = NO;

    return marker;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either remove and re-add the annotation, forcing an annotation layer redraw, or you can look into this patch which will allow you to call for a layer redraw:

https://github.com/tracyharton/mapbox-ios-sdk/commit/31cda12f5bcc04dad42db2e07558b95eb43604a7